How can I create increasing random strings?
I have been trying to create a step in my JMeter test to simulate an increasing string throughout the duration of the test.
I have seen the randomString function which seems perfect but I can't find a way to have the first parameter changing.
I have a Counter in my test which starts at 0, to then increase by 1 at each interation so my first thought would have been to use something like:
${__RandomString(${counter},abcdefjhijklmnopqrtsuvwxyz1234567890,nameOfOutput)}


But this keeps failing at run time telling me that Counter is a String.
I have also tried to have running a more generic RandomString with:
${__RandomString(${__Random(100,4500,)},abcdefjhijklmnopqrtsuvwxyz1234567890,nameOfOutput)}

which works fine, but my JMeter returns a 500 error code when executing that step (even tho it will provide the random string) with this reason:
2024-10-22 16:52:03,247 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script Create Random String, message: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: jv03nn8zfzntdzates8i4w9s160owr2xx4rtor4x3tnec4h8xpidmv4760o84n49x39kuyzy55ybjoe8f6p58b7o9btjp0ocntnr2wshj069qhli3awf96f31b7pjae8jpck1q4o9xqthey5dko38djydh0hdun4y7n4ccblvetzuoo41jw7ssn3jx3sjjk63s2w12b634luln6p8bdu65sjqz48t92j6vytpqjcfblo3avbj0ef9c7ozzva08mia5syjae0tc50oi5p3f1jys for class: Script15
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: jv03nn8zfzntdzates8i4w9s160owr2xx4rtor4x3tnec4h8xpidmv4760o84n49x39kuyzy55ybjoe8f6p58b7o9btjp0ocntnr2wshj069qhli3awf96f31b7pjae8jpck1q4o9xqthey5dko38djydh0hdun4y7n4ccblvetzuoo41jw7ssn3jx3sjjk63s2w12b634luln6p8bdu65sjqz48t92j6vytpqjcfblo3avbj0ef9c7ozzva08mia5syjae0tc50oi5p3f1jys for class: Script15

What am I doing wrong?

The options are in:

Surround the function with quotation marks. However as per JSR223 Sampler documentation it will result into caching the compiled value and generated string will be "random" during first iteration only

Pass it via "Parameters" section like


Use RandomStringUtils class instead:
String randomString = org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(100, 4500)



More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?
